# Payment options with radio buttons in the contact form

Tags: html, forms, auto-responder

My form is currently set up to gather all the input data to my autoresponder...however, I made the form with only one option - pay now. Users would like options, so Im thinking of giving them 2 choices, the old "pay now" COD method, and option#2 paypal. I think radio buttons are the best way for doing this. However I cant get them to work separately...when I choose option 2, option 1 remains selected. So I added the radio buttons myself after the ordernow button.

```
<p>mail: *</p>
<p>
<label>
<input type="text" class="wf-input wf-req wf-valid__email" name="mail" class="mj" ></input>
</label>
</p>
<p>name: *</p>
<p>
<label>
<input type="text" class="wf-input wf-req wf-valid__required" name="name" class="mj" ></input>
</label>
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit" value="ORDER NOW" class="butt">
<div class="selectpaymentradios">
<label class="radio" >select payment</label>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="cash" value="cash" checked /> <span>Ca$h</span>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="ppal" value="ppal" /> <span>PaypaL</span>
</div>
<input type="hidden" name="webform_id" value="12x45"/>
</p>  
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://xyz.com/view_webform.js?wid=12x45&mg_param1=1"></script>
```

Im trying to figure out how can I make this work with my autoresponder, I think this form has to be able to tell me what kind of payment did the customer chose...but the autoresponders form creator doesnt have radio buttons at all so Im stuck, I dont know if its possible...

Answer (score 1):

```
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="cash" value="cash" checked /> <span>Ca$h</span>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="ppal" value="ppal" /> <span>PaypaL</span>
```

the problem you hit, is very simple - you have to use the same name for all radio-buttons, where only one item should be selected. like this:

```
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="payment" value="cash" checked /> <span>Ca$h</span>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="payment" value="ppal" /> <span>PaypaL</span>
```

Comment: more information about radio: http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/radio or http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.radio.html

Answer (score 0):

The `name` attribute should be the same for both radio buttons:

```
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="method" value="cash" checked="checked" /> <span>Ca$h</span>
<input class="radio" type="radio" name="method" value="ppal" /> <span>PaypaL</span>
```

Also, if you are closing `input` tags, you are probably worried about XHTML validation. So instead of just `checked` you should type `checked="checked"`.